# How to update value in object?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I work with Typescript and I want update value in object, but only when the statement is true, if statement is false then old value should be still in this object, look at the code:

```
isUpdated: boolean;

const updatedObject: Object = {
     updatedAt: isUpdated ? new Date() : "old value, nothing to change"
}
```

like in the example above, when `isUpdated` is true, then my `updatedAt` should be update to the new value from `new Date()`, but when my `isUpdated` is false, then i want to still have my old value in the object, I don't want to use a big `if` statement and create a massive code for this simple operation, can somoene tell me how to do this?

thanks for any help!

Comment: Try to give a bigger picture, where is your existing `updatedObject`?

Comment: where is the old value coming from? i dont see that

Comment: Do you want to set `updatedAt` when _any_ property on your object is changed? Then you might want to use [decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html)...

Comment: @Cerbrus hmm no, this is over engineering

Comment: Then what exactly _do_ you want?

Comment: update object only when `isUpdated` is true, and not update when `isUpdated` is false, your idea with decorators is good but this is too big for this simple case

Comment: When you need to update an object, you will need to have access to that object, in your question, We don't see that object anywhere?

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to *set* `updatedAt` when you assign a new value to `isUpdated`. You can't do that when you try to access it.

This will do the trick:

```
class MyClass {
    private _isUpdated: boolean;    
    get isUpdated(): boolean { return this._isUpdated; }    
    set isUpdated(value: boolean) {
        this.updatedAt = new Date();
        this._isUpdated = value;
    }

    updatedAt: Date;
}
```